# Отправить скриншот! html2canvas

Tags: javascript, html2canvas

Доброго времени суток)

Моя задача отправить скрин элемента на другую страницу или на почту. Использую для этого html2canvas. Скрин сделать получилось, даже вставить его на эту же страницу. Но как отправить его куда то дальше не могу разобраться. Пытался через localStorage, но не вышло. Какие идеи есть?

```
html2canvas(document.getElementById("auto")).then(function(canvas) {

  canvas.toDataURL();

  document.getElementById("screen").appendChild(my_screen);`
```

Comment: необходимо отправить данные на сервер и там сделать необходимое

Comment: Ага, ага. Если нет другого выхода, то можно подробнее об отправке на сервер и необходимом

Comment: А что с localStorage не вышло?

Comment: @АртёмКириллов localstorage, конечно, тоже может помочь... что у Вас не сработало?

Comment: @Stranger in the Q Я пытаюсь загрузить скрин на localstorage, предварительно пытаясь перевести его в строку, с помощью JSON.stringify(my_screen). Но не вышло, получилось так, что перевелось в объект:   screen: "{}"     -  вот так

Comment: @АртёмКириллов используйте base64 кодирование картинки

Comment: @Stranger in the Q Разве я не сделал это?  canvas.toDataURL(); - это не оно? Если нет, то как?

Comment: @АртёмКириллов нет, это голый бинарь, сама картинка, используйте btoa(...) и atob(...)

Comment: @Stranger in the Q  Отличный совет, спастбо. Но всё равно есть проблема( Я закодировал, получил строку. Занёс это в объект, после объект закинул в localstorage. На другой странице раскодировал и получил  [object HTMLCanvasElement]  , но не картинку(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Воспользуйтесь упаковкой бинарных данных, которые Вы получаете методом `toDataURL`, в base64 и обратно при помощи встроенных в API браузера методов `btoa()` И `atob()`.
2. То что вы раскодируете - просто подставьте в атрибут `src` тега `img`

```js
let c = canvas.getContext('2d');

for(var i=0; i<10; i++) {
  c.fillStyle = `hsl(${Math.random()*360},55%,55%)`;
  c.fillRect(Math.random()*150, Math.random()*100, 50, 50);
}
  
function canvas2img() {
  let str = btoa(canvas.toDataURL('png'));
  console.log('str', str);
  img.setAttribute('src', atob(str));
}
```

```css
canvas, img {border:solid}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=200 ></canvas>
<button onclick="canvas2img()" >canvas2img</button>
<img id="img">
```

Comment: О даааа! Спасибо, всё работает)